# Solved problems book in Mathematical statistics

Tags: reference-request, statistics

Are there some solved problems book in Mathematical statistics?
Or some set of solutions for qualifying exams preparation?

Say to the level of

[Casella, Berger, Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126), or,
[Hogg et al., Introduction to Mathematical Statistics](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FIntroduction-Mathematical-Statistics-Robert-Hogg%2Fdp%2F0130085073&ei=YqOlUNOsAdTC0AG18YDgBw&usg=AFQjCNEnawjboKR4wnAGRtVJXGD4Z6KnrA&sig2=_YPsS7TwNzeUJ58WNMpXDA).

I'm preparing for a qualifying exam on this subject.